# How to sum up value in string

Tags: c++, string

Well I try to sum up strings that contains number(only) in ex.

```
std::string a = "103";
std::string b = "13";
```

And I want it to sum up so the result will be 116

I was wondering about `substring` or `charAt` but I don't know if an approach using either of these is a good one.

I hope that's well explained.

Comment: And did you try doing it? If yes, show us the code.

Comment: @HappyCoder nope not yet im just started learning C++ if one of this resolve is good just tell me which one and i do it myself but i still dunno how heh but dont post code :)

Comment: Forgive me my mistake there should be string not String i have a bad habit from java

Comment: `103 + 13 == 113`???

Comment: You couldn't use `string a = 103;`. It will show `error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type`. Use `string a = "103";`

Comment: @jblixr I took it as obvious

Comment: @Bulit yes it is obvious, that you do not need strings to add `103+13`...

Comment: @tobi303 If i got string variable.... and i pointed it in title?

Comment: yes then it still is obvious that adding `103` and `13` is better done with `int`s than with `string`s. `string a = "103"` looks a bit strange, because you are "converting" a integer value to a string to do calculations. I guess in your real problem, the strings are coming from somewhere (but not just hardcoded integers), but then still the easiest is to convert them back to `int`s.

Comment: @tobi303 really if i got int then the question will be different but here i'm asking about string so plz if u dont like that question then just go by and dont make here spam really. Question is not about converting string to int but about sum up string value so plz just stop.

Comment: I just wanted to point out, that it seems like you are making things more complicated than necessary, because in the example you show, the values that you assign to the strings are indeed integer values. And btw you accepted an answer that can be summarized as: "convert the strings to integers" so I really dont know what you are complaining about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `String` is a `std::string` then

`std::stoi(a) + std::stoi(b)` is one way.

But note that `a` and `b` must contain only character sequences that are convertible to integral types, *and* each argument to `+`, along with the total must *not* overflow an `int`.

If that is not the case then consider `std::stol`, 'std::stoll', or `std::stod`. Note that `std::stoll` is good for a 64 bit unsigned integral type.

Comment: What if it overflow int? I need this in Fibonacci sequence for n = max 100000. So i make my own bigint.

Comment: A `std::stoll` should be adequate: a `long long` must be at least 64 bits.

Comment: @Bathsheba This solution wont work for the Fibonacci sequence since values for n > 100 will exceed the range for `unsigned long long` (with 64 bits). However it's still a valid answer to the question.

Comment: Re: "note that `a` and `b` must be integral types": `a` and `b` are `std::string` objects, so they are **never** integral types. The constraint is that each must contain a character sequence that can be converted to an integral type.

Comment: @PeteBecker: That is a good point; precision is important. Thank you.

Comment: @Bathsheba - you and I can talk in shorthand; for beginners that precision is important.

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved using `std::istringstream`.

```
int iA, iB;
std::istringstream(a) >> iA;
std::istringstream(b) >> iB;

int sum = iA + iB;
```

If you're using a custom class as you've mentioned in a comment you can override the `operator>>` and still use the above solution.